# How to plot a list of value from a .dat file?

Tags: plotting, import, data, data-acquisition

So I received from a professor a .dat file, which does contain a quite large amount of points. The problem is this: this file is structured as I'm going to show in figure below:

[image]

The first value at the left is the $t$ value, that is the argument of our function $\Phi_{\nu}(t)$, where as the following values are the $\nu$ values. So for example the second value from the left is the value of $\Phi(t)$ for that given $t$, and for $\nu = 0.01$. The third value is $\Phi(t)$ for that $t$ (always the first element at the left side) and for $\nu = 0.25$ and so on.

The last value at the right side is a different function, which is, as written, $e^{-t/2}$

The values are written in rows as a list of points, with the exception that every row does contain a single point for the $\Phi_{\nu}(t)$, and when you plot the whole, you shall get a plot with SIX functions.

The question is: how could I plot the functions separately, or even better altogether? Is there a way to do this? Of course this image is reduced, and the total number of points is very big.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I tried with 
    labdata = Import[phi.dat];
    rawdata = ListPlot[labdata]

But it gave me something completely wrong, like si vertical lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Say, you get this with `Import`

> data = {{"#", " time", "nu=0.01", " nu=0.25", "nu=0.50", "nu=0.75", "nu=1.0", "phi(t)=exp<-t/2)"},
>      {0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.},
>       {0.0019999999999999999, 0.999245, 0.999124, 0.999971, 0.999942, 
>       0.999, 0.9995},
>      {0.0020000000000000000, 0.99873, 0.998292, 0.998104, 0.998049, 
>       0.998002, 0.999},
>      {0.0030000000000000001, 0.998218, 0.997481, 0.997149, 0.997058, 
>       0.997005, 0.998501},
>      {0.0040000000000000001, 0.997706, 0.996684, 0.996201, 0.996071, 
>       0.99601, 0.998002},
>      {0.00500000000000000010, 0.997195, 0.995898, 0.995261, 0.995087, 
>       0.995016, 0.997503},
>      {0.0060000000000000001, 0.996685, 0.995121, 0.994328, 0.994105, 
>       0.994024, 0.997004},
>      {0.0070000000000000002, 0.996176, 0.994353, 0.993401, 0.993127, 
>       0.993033, 0.996506},
>      {0.0080000000000000002, 0.995667, 0.993591, 0.992479, 0.992151, 
>       0.992044, 0.996008}};

and you want to plot column 3,6 and 7 against column 2.

```
head = data[[1]];
data = data[[2 ;; -1]];
nx = 2;
nrows = {3,6,7};
ListLinePlot[Table[data[[All, {nx, n}]], {n, nrows}], 
             PlotLegends -> Table[head[[n]], {n, nrows}]]
```

[image]

If you want to plot against column 1, then change `nx=1`.

Comment: OH MY. Thank you thank you thank you!!

Comment: If I wanted to exclude the second line too (the one for $\nu = 0.01$) should I change $-1$ into $-2$?

Comment: @HenryTuring Just change the columns in your `nrows` list.